# Closed and Open set clarification

Tags: general-topology

Why is $[a,\infty)$ both closed and open in the lower limit topology $\mathbb{R}_l$, actually I do get why it is closed (because it is the complement of the open set $(-\infty, a),$ but I do not get why it is considered open.

Generally speaking if I have some set $[2,5),$ if I want to check this set is open, then do I compute its complement and see if its closed? For instance, the complement of $[2,5)$ seems to be $(-\infty,2) \cup [5,\infty)$, but I fail to see how this is closed. Could anyone give me some thorough explanation regarding this confusion? Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is the lower limit topology? Are you working on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Yes the $\mathbb{R}_{l}$ is the topology I am talking about. I will edit the post.

Comment: $[a, \infty)$ can be written as union of half open intervals (and those form a basis for the topology you describe). Since a topology is closed under unions, the set is open

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's open as $[a,\infty) = \bigcup_{n=0}^\infty [a+n, a+n+1)$ which is a union of open sets in the lower limit (Sorgenfrey) topology.

Comment: Thank you, but I do not understand why $[a+n,a+n+1)$ is necessarily an open set?

Comment: Look at the definition of the topology. It is the topology generated by all half open intervals. I.e., half open intervals are a basis and by definition open.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis By definition.

Comment: So it is just by definition open because any subset in a topology is defined to be an open subset? Is there a way to show that it actually is open?

Comment: @AuroraBorealis being open by definition means being in the topology (a set of subsets). It’s synonymous. And half-open intervals are in the lower limit topology by definition.

Comment: I think I am getting mixed up with the definition of open subsets for metric spaces and topological spaces. Thank you for the replies and help.

Comment: @AuroraBorealis If it helps: a set $O$ is open in the lower limit topology iff for all $x \in O$ there is some $r>0$ such that $[x,x+r) \subseteq O$. This is sort of similar to the metric definition (it uses a variant of  a metric). It's also easy to check for your $[a,\infty)$ set.

Comment: Yes this helps alot, thank you very much !

Comment: @AuroraBorealis just to add: there is no *the* definition for topological spaces of open subsets. A topological space is a set with a topology (which you have define; it has to obey certain axioms though). The same set can have a lot of different topologies, creating a lot of different topological spaces.